# .htaccess friendly URLs weird behavior

Tags: php, .htaccess, mime-types, friendly-url

I have a `query.php` file on my server whose location is `ROOT_DIRECTORY/info/query.php`.

There is no problem with the script untill i used friendly Urls in my .htaccess file.I have used them to many scripts and they are working perfectly fine but when i add these two lines

```
RewriteRule info/([a-zA-Z]*)/ info/query.php?slot=$1

RewriteRule info/([a-zA-Z]*) info/query.php?slot=$1
```

in my .htaccess file for my query.php file it gives me the following errors.

> > Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/info/css/reset.css".
> >
> > Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/info/css/style.css".
> >
> > (index):27 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

However, when i remove those two lines in the .htaccess file , there is no error and my script runs as expected.

What could be the problem ? What am i doing wrong that is causing such unexpected behavior?

Thanks!

If, anyone wants the query.php file , i can upload it as well.Please write in comments for the code.

Comment: My best guess, but this might not solve your problem: The rewrite rules rewrite all files, including your css files, not just your php or html files. Try to restrict it to those files only.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about this info, i didn't know about it.How would i restrict it to that particular file?

Comment: Something like: `RewriteRule ^info/(.*)\.php$ info/query.php?slot=$1` (untested), but better have a look at the manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Thanks, man.It worked,write the answer and i will select it correct.

Comment: Wow, I really didn't expect that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you also 'rewrite' your CSS files. So they will also be processed by `query.php`. This is not what you want.

Try to restrict the rewrite rule to PHP files only like this:

```
RewriteRule ^info/(.*)\.php$ info/query.php?slot=$1
```

This will also do it for all file names, even if they are named something like: `this_is_my_file.php`.